# Plot values from a column on R

Tags: r, plot

I have a shape file of data and I want to apply RK on values from only one column of my shp.

The column name is "Fabric" and contains these values:

```
V
S
M
```

I tried to separate the values using that, but I get an error:

```
pots = read.csv(file="C:\\Users\\HP\\folder\\Pots.csv", sep='\t')

pots #displays all columns and values
 
plot(subset(Pots,Fabric=="V"))

Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'plot': object 'Fabric' not found
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: You have `Pots` and `pots` in the code you provided, which is different. Please show `colnames(pots)` (or `colnames(Pots)` ??). Additionally I do not think plotting by giving directly the subset dataframe will work

Comment: Thanks, I tried it both ways and the result was the same. The colnames() function works properly: colnames(pottery)
[1] "Object.Shape.Use.Rim.Diameter.Body.Diameter.Base.Diameter.Height.Fabric.Decoration.Pattern.Style.Floor.Fill." But still I cannot separate the data

Comment: Now in the example you give, your data is `pottery`, it is difficult to understand your post with 3 different dataframe names. Your `pottery` dataframe contains a single column so effectively there is not any single column `Fabric` in your dataframe. You need to properly import your data. I believe your file is not a correctly formatted .csv file. You need to identify the column separator in your file (maybe a space or a ; ?). Please check the separator and modify your `read.csv` `sep` argument accordingly

Comment: This question was tagged `spatstat` but it seems to be unrelated to the `spatstat` package.